# Largest superprime number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Call a number n a superprime if every consecutive block of digits in n is also a prime. For example, the number 3727 contains the blocks 37 and 727, which are prime, but it also contains the blocks 72 and 372, which are composite, so 3727 is not a superprime. (The blocks can be of any size. In particular, if n is a superprime, then all the digits in n are prime, and n itself is prime.) Find the largest super prime number. 
How do I develop constraints on the value of superprimes(giving a first glance, I thought the answer to be infinite)

Comment: Hint: Try to show that if there are enough digits, then some block of length at least $2$ will be divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number can only consist of $2;3;5;7$. $2;5$ can only be the first digit, otherwise at least one block would end either in $2$ or $5$ so it wouldn't be prime. Apart from the first digit, it can only consist of $3;7$. Two equal digits cannot be next to each other (divisible by $11$). If furthermore the length of the $73$ or $37$ strip is more than four digits, at least one block would be divisible by $101$. So the longest possible strips are $373$ and $737$, but $737$ is divisible by $11$. If either $2$ or $5$ are followed by at least $2$ digits of the form described above, then those first three digits would be divisible by $3$ since their sum would be divisible by $3$. Therefore, starting with $2$ or $5$ would result in a two digit number. But $373$ is a super prime, and therefore it is the largest.

Comment: I was asked the super prime (mod 100). The question is not a trick question. So I think the answer should have more than 3 digits.

Comment: But is there a fault in my argumentation? I didn't think of it as a trick question.